# How can I redirect traffic from Port 80 to Port 443 using UFW?

Tags: nginx, https, ubuntu-18.04, nat, ufw

I use Ubuntu Server 18.04 and wish to forward/redirect traffic from port 80 to port 443 (`https`).

I want to do this as I have SSL on NGINX(port 80) and a Flask app running on Gunicorn on port 443. I can't make NGINX proxy requests as the app isn't in a `virtualenv`.

I wish to use UFW. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Redirecting http to https traffic is not the purpose of a firewall like `ufw`.

You should redirect the requests within `NGINX` as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}
```

... where 80 is the http port, `example.org` is your domain, and `301` indicates the browser that the resource is accessible at the other place.